DynamicJson enabling in NpgSql
I have updated few days ago .NET version in my project to 8. Also Npgsql.EntityFrameworkCore.PostgreSQL package have been updated to version 8.0.10.
Some part of my code inserts a class Entity into DB, where column partitions has type JsonB
public sealed class Entity
{
    public int Version { get; set; }

    public IReadOnlyCollection<Partition>? Partitions { get; set; } = new List<Partition>().AsReadOnly();
}

and the Partition
public sealed class Partition
{
    public string Name { get; set; } = string.Empty;

    public IReadOnlyCollection<Category> Categories { get; set; } = new List<Category>().AsReadOnly();
}

So now when I try to insert Entity to db using npgsql
await _dbContext.AddAsync(Entity, cancellationToken);

I`ve got an error which says me to Enable DynamicJson in NpgsqlDataSourceBuilder
(Link to description)
So here main problem arises.
To make an NpgsqlDataSourceBuilder instance a connection string have to be put into constructor.
My connection string looks like
Host=host-1:port,host-2:port;Target Session Attributes=primary;Database=db_name;Password=password;

But new NpgsqlDataSourceBuilder(connectionString).EnableDynamicJson().Build() with such a connection string returns an error
System.InvalidOperationException When creating a multi-host data source, TargetSessionAttributes cannot be specified. Create without TargetSessionAttributes, and then obtain DataSource wrappers from it. Consult the docs for more information. 
Unfortunately, I`m not able to change a connection string.
I tried to insert Entity using LinqToDB, but caught the same issue about DynamicJson enabling in NpgsqlDataSourceBuilder.
Also I tried to parse connection string using DbConnectionStringBuilder(), then make a new string without TargetSessionAttributes. But it seems like a bad solution for some cases.
So my question is:
Is there any way to enable DynamicJson in NpgsqlDataSourceBuilder with my connection string or to insert my c# Class to JsonB type column in DB?
I will be grateful for any advice. Thanks in advance

Please try adding this piece of code NpgsqlConnection.GlobalTypeMapper.EnableDynamicJson(); as mentioned in this page https://www.npgsql.org/doc/types/json.html?tabs=global
